# Screencasting with explanation boxes

Tags: linux, screencasts

I wanted to make a video demonstration of one software. I wanted to use text description instead of using voice description, a simple example of what I've explained could be [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=00lrC4NFvzg) short screencasting, where author uses short text messages instead of explaining it with his own voice.

Could you recommend any free software for doing such a screencasting please? Would be better if it works in Ubuntu or if it is a web application.

**UPDATE**

I have found out [Wink](http://www.debugmode.com/wink/) which could add explanations boxes as I said. Now the problem is that it doesn't support Linux 64bit, has only 32bit. Any other app like Wink for 64bit Linux?

Comment: was in the same position and found this post helpful.
Further I would recommend `simplescreencast` (its in the debian repos) as a lighweight and efficient gui-tool for capturing the screen (not overloaded but really intuitive for basic capturing)
To edit/annotate I read about `kdenlive` (I needed to load 200-300 MB of packages) BUT
Another way is using a screen annotation tool like `compiz-annotate`, `ardesia` or `pylote` (see askubuntu.com/questions/328543/drawing-over-the-desktop) and pause the recording before editing...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the person who made that video may have actually added the text overlays after recording the original screencast using a video editor.  If you're not trying to broadcast your screencast live, then this would work fine for you. [Cinellera](http://cinelerra.org/) and [Kino](http://www.kinodv.org/) are great on Ubuntu/Kubuntu and [Lightworks](http://www.lightworksbeta.com/) is a very robust but open source option for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find any free screen casters that allow you to add text. I know Camtasia for Windows has this capability. I would recommend using a regular screen caster, a list of which is given here: [ScreenCasting in Ubuntu](http://ubuntulinuxhelp.com/is-there-any-good-screencasting-in-ubuntu/) and then using a video editing software to add the annotations after, as Keith B. [suggested](https://superuser.com/questions/316284/screencasting-with-text-description/316287#316287).